# How to split a string into a smaller part of string

Tags: php, string

I have a variable like this:

```
$str = 'loremipsum Gol A WB=10 PRC=7|Gol O TC=8 PRC=12|Gol B WB=170 PRC=17|Gol AB WB=0 TC=1 url';
```

I want to split `Gol A WB=10`, `Gol A PRC=7`, `Gol O TC=8`, etc as an independent string, so I can process another function to the string. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
before, thank you for the answers, but Im sorry your answers are not the answer that I need. So far, I got this

```
$string_array = array("abc string 1 abc","abc string 2 abc" ,"abc string 3 abc");

foreach($string_array as $string){

echo getBetween($string,"abc","abc") . "<br>";

}
```

and my problem is I dont have the same word to get rid off, but a different words, so the code that I need, I believe wouldn't be

```
echo getBetween($string,**"abc","abc"**) . "<br>";
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: See if my edit works. Your original question was not very clear and did not really reflect what you were really looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'loremipsum Gol A WB=10 PRC=7|Gol O TC=8 PRC=12|Gol B WB=170 PRC=17|Gol AB WB=0 TC=1 url';
preg_match_all('/Gol(.*?)[0-9]/',$str,$matches);
foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    echo "<li>{$match}</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you mean, but maybe one one of these?:

```
<?php
$str = 'loremipsum Gol A WB=10 PRC=7|Gol O TC=8 PRC=12|Gol B WB=170 PRC=17|Gol AB WB=0 TC=1 url';
preg_match_all('/(Gol [A-Z]{1,2} [A-Z\=0-9]{1,})/',$str,$matched);

print_r($matched[1]);
print_r(preg_replace('/'.implode("|",$matched[1]).'/',"",$str));
print_r(implode("|",$matched[1]));
?>
```

Gives you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Gol A WB=10
    [1] => Gol O TC=8
    [2] => Gol B WB=170
    [3] => Gol AB WB=0
)

loremipsum  PRC=7| PRC=12| PRC=17| TC=1 url

Gol A WB=10|Gol O TC=8|Gol B WB=170|Gol AB WB=0
```

---

**Edit:** Your original request was not very clear, but you may need something like a wrapped `preg_match()`.

```
function extract_val($str,$reg1="",$reg2="")
    {
        preg_match('/^'.$reg1.'(.*)'.$reg2.'$/', $str,$matched);
        return (isset($matched[1]))? $matched[1]:false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$str = 'loremipsum Gol A WB=10 PRC=7|Gol O TC=8 PRC=12|Gol B WB=170 PRC=17|Gol AB WB=0 TC=1 url';
$chunks=explode('|', $str); //Split your string by |
foreach($chunks as $chunk){ //iterate through chunks
echo $chunk;
//process here using chunk...
}
```